# HTML5: W3C github explanations vs. Technical Report

Tags: html

I was reading about the **<article>** tag, and faced with two definitions for the tag; two separate examples!

Here's [github](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-article-element) vs. [Technical Report](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element)

The github version omits the fact that `article` is suitable for comments, and in it's example uses `ol` for showing comments. but **TR**, uses `article` for each individual comment.

why are there difference? Are functionalities and purpose of tags changing?

Comment: You may want to look into [the History of HTML5](http://mashable.com/2012/07/17/history-html5/#qP2x854gikqH) to better understand.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't understand why is there two flavors. both being Technical Reports of **W3C** [1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sections.html#the-article-element) and [2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element)

Comment: Your first link is to HTML 5.1, the second to HTML 5.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan So, my question is that, with this minor version change, they are changing the way article was used? for example, for comments. because you can't find descriptions to use article for comments in 5.1 spec.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Actually 5.2 but who's counting :)

Comment: (BTW, the github link in the post is to HTML 5.2). I have no idea. I'm not on the W3. I expect you could search the [issues list on their github page](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues) to find out why it was changed.

Comment: @War10ck I was talking about the first link in the comment, not the OP.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan My mistake. It was all in good fun anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/110) explains the reasoning for the change to `article`. I'll quote part of it for posterity:

> The major differences between the current article definition and the updated definition:
>
> - What article represents is more prescribed
> - definition has been simplified
> - Wording around syndication and its relationship to atom 'entry' has been removed along with other 'in principle' statements
>     definition:
> - Advice/explanation of how AT may expose has been added
> - The **should** level requirement to add a heading has been emphasised.
> - examples have been updated

And [a subsequent comment](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/110#issuecomment-190275725) talks specifically about the use of `article` for comments:

> … user submitted comments would be better not marked up as `<article>` elements as the meaning of `<article>` becomes over generalised, degrading the semantics. It is arguable whether user submitted comments are complete and self contained compositions as their meaning is directly tied to the context of the parent article. Also it does not often make sense to include individual user comments in the document outline and if this is deemed useful they can be marked up with a `<section>` element and child heading per comment. For SemWeb purposes schema.org annotations are much better to denote granular semantics such as *this is a comment*.

Comment: So, we can say, definitions are changing or getting updated. right?

Comment: Yes, HTML5 was envisioned as a "living standard", getting updated almost continuously as implementations fleshed out the standard.

Comment: I'm sorry to continuing this discussions, but, what happens to **codes** that rely on the statement "use article for comments" and now says something different. you get used to to use something, they decide to change tomorrow. no consistency.

Comment: The code remains the same, and likely browsers' parsing of the code remains the same. The standard defines how the element should be used. How it's actually used is up to authors. In the future, *maybe* search engines *might* use the semantic meanings of the elements to enhance searching, but I'm guessing not very quickly, considering how many sites still use the `font` tag :).